# Routes - react-router v5 - hitting NotFound always

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I am trying to add a Landing page for my application. After the authorization. The routes after landing page is always hitting the NotFound route. I am unable to figure out the reason.

The initial routes are :

```
const Initial = ({ settings }) => {
  const store = setupStore(reducers, { settings });
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <AuthProvider appSettings={settings}>
        <Router basename={settings.AppContextPath}>
          <MainLayout>
            <Switch>
              <Route
                path={LOGIN_URL}
                component={Login}
              />
              <Route
                path={LOGOUT_URL}
                component={Logout}
              />
              <Route
                exact={true}
                path={SILENT_RENEW_URL}
                component={SilentRenew}
              />
              <AuthenticatedRoute>
                <App>
                  <Switch>
                    <Route
                      exact path="/"
                      component={LandingPage}
                    />
                    <Route component={NotFound} />
                  </Switch>
                </App>
              </AuthenticatedRoute>
            </Switch>
          </MainLayout>
        </Router>
      </AuthProvider>
    </Provider>
  );
};
```

In the `LandingPage` component I have added rest of the routes which should be based on clicking the `Link` from Landing Page:

```
const FeatureRoutes = () => {
  return (
    <Switch>
      <Route
        path={`/:Id/feature1`}
        component={Feature1}
      />
      <Route
        path={`/:Id/feature2`}
        component={Feature2}
      />            
      <Route exact path={`/:Id`} component={Features} />
    </Switch>
  );
};

export default FeatureRoutes;
```

Clicking the link navigates correctly to url with `"/:id"`, but it shows `NotFound` page.

Please let me know which part I am doing wrong.

Comment: Try removing the `exact` prop from the `Route` component that leads to `LandingPage`

Comment: The 'Features' component get displayed under the LandingPage if i do that, i had already tried it.

Comment: Nested routes won't display if the parent route is passed the `exact` prop.

Answer (score 1):

i could solve it to go till 'Features' route by changing the route so :

```
<AuthProvider appSettings={settings}>
                <Router basename={settings.AppContextPath}>
                    <MainLayout>
                        <Switch>
                            Route
                                path={LOGIN_URL}
                                component={Login}
                            />
                            <Route
                                path={LOGOUT_URL}
                                component={Logout}
                            />
                            <Route
                                exact={true}
                                path={SILENT_RENEW_URL}
                                component={SilentRenew}
                            />
                            <AuthenticatedRoute>
                                <App>
                                    <Switch>
                                        <Route
                                            exact path="/"
                                            component={LandingPage}
                                        />
                                        <Route
                                            path={'/:Id'}
                                            component={FeatureRoutes}
                                        />
                                    </Switch>
                                </App>
                            </AuthenticatedRoute>
                        </Switch>
                    </MainLayout>
                </Router>
            </AuthProvider>
        </Provider>
    );
};
```

I moved the NotFound route into FeatureRoutes.